# transform rotate property taking up orginal space

Tags: html, css

i have a design in which i have to transform a specific text with respect to an postion absolute div here is my [fiddle](https://output.jsbin.com/xonilovoji/)

now without the `transform: rotate(270deg)` property they are positioned perfectly on top on each other this is what i actually want

[image]

now when i apply `transform: rotate(270deg)` it totally leave its original area and comes in center like this
[image]

my question is how can i remove the white space that comes due to the `transform` property so that it is transformed but exactly where it is positioned naturally without transform!

here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="index-section2">

        <div class="display-inline-block">
            <img src="http://nextcrawl.co/website/phase-img.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="pos-abs">
                <h3>Phase 1</h3>
                <h4>Sold out</h4>
                <h5>mcity condos</h5>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="index-section2">

        <div class="display-inline-block">
            <img src="http://nextcrawl.co/website/phase-img.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="pos-abs">
                <h3>Phase 2</h3>
                <h4>Available</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="pos-abs2">
                <h5>mcity condos</h5>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="index-section2">

        <div class="display-inline-block">
            <img src="http://nextcrawl.co/website/phase-img.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="pos-abs">
                <h3>Phase 3</h3>
                <h4>To Be Announced</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="pos-abs2">
                <h5>mcity condos</h5>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.index-section2{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.3%;
}
.index-section2 .display-inline-block{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.index-section2 .opacity{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    left: 13%;
    height: 93%;
    width: 87%;
}
.index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs h5{
    /* transform: rotate(270deg); */
}
.index-section2 .display-inline-block img{
    width: 100%;
}

.index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs h3 , .index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs h4 , .index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs h5 , .index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs2 h5{
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs h3 {
    font-family: "antonio-regular";
    font-size: 40px;
}
.index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs h4 {
    font-family: "antonio-light";
    font-size: 30px;
}
.index-section2 .display-inline-block .pos-abs h5 {
    font-family: "antonio-light";
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 95px;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code here ?

Comment: @AbdiHamid DONE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
}
#rot {
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  top: 340px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rot">aaa</div>
<div>bbb</div>
```

Both `position: absolute` and `float: left` should work depending on how you wanna position your content.

Comment: thanks for the reply! the aaa div still gets in the center whereas i want it exactly below bbb div

Comment: You can change the positioning using either `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` properties or `margin`

Comment: ya that is the main issue if i lets suppose add left:-13% that does works but only on my screen it is not generic when screen size increases it positions also disrupts

Comment: I've updated the answer. That should help if I'm not wrong.

Comment: perfect this is what i was looking now it stays the same on every screen ! perfect man thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `transform: rotate(270deg) translate(0,100%)` and `transform-origin: bottom left` and `bottom: 0` on your `h5` element. Then do something like `bottom: 55px` on your `.pos-abs` element to taste.